# iOS - How to inject gc_keys.json file on runtime in gitHub workflow using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, google-cloud-storage, fastlane, github-actions

I am trying to implement github CI using Google Cloud Storage but I am unable to run it on workflow. But how can I inject gc_keys.json file on runtime.

check this link [https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sync_code_signing/#google-cloud-storage-access]

GOOGLE CLOUD STORAGE ACCESS
Accessing Google Cloud Storage from your CI system requires you to provide the gc_keys.json file as part of your build. How you implement this is your decision. You can inject that file during build time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/iOS-Code-Signing-amp-Provisioning/m-p/36480/highlight/true#M2587 might be related.

Comment: @banyan I already saw this link, it doesn't tell us about SECRETS thing

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look into [this](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow) which talks about "Using encrypted secrets in a workflow".

There is an example using Bash:

```
steps:
  - shell: bash
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    run: |
      example-command "$SUPER_SECRET"
```

Example using PowerShell

```
steps:
  - shell: pwsh
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    run: |
      example-command "$env:SUPER_SECRET"
```

Example using Cmd.exe

```
steps:
  - shell: cmd
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    run: |
      example-command "%SUPER_SECRET%"
```

Also there are some limiations using secrets, such as you can not exceed 100 secrets per workflow.